# Safety stock calculation for Intermittent demand components

Tags: probability, python, forecasting

I'm trying to solve this supply chain problem where I have to determine safety stock calculation for the components/raw materials that we procure... First I analysed the demand or consumption pattern of components and classified them into smooth, Intermittent, erratic and lumpy based on coefficient of variation and average demand interval..
Could you please suggest on how to setup safety stock for Intermittent,erratic and lumpy demand pattern components...Could you please explain this with an example

Thank you

Comment: For intermittent demands, you could take a look at [Boylan & Syntetos (2001) *Intermittent Demand Forecasting*](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Intermittent+Demand+Forecasting:+Context,+Methods+and+Applications-p-9781119976080), they cover a lot of useful parametric distributions. Then it's a question of selecting the target service level and calculating quantile forecasts based on the predictive distribution for total demand over the lead time. Lumpy demands are a lot harder, because there are essentially no useful distributions.

Comment: Thank you Stephan. But is there a article or an example on how to setup safety stock for components that have intermittent or erratic demand pattern?

Comment: I am unfortunately not aware of any papers that explicitly consider this, although I would assume something exists. Most of the literature I am familiar with mainly looks at forecasting intermittent demand, perhaps with distributional forecasts. How you turn that into safety stocks depends on your supply chain, especially lead times. In the simplest possible case, you can place an order every evening, and product arrives the next morning. Then you simply order-up-to your desired service level. (The exact definition of your service level may also become important.)